# Elasticsearch 7 and Nest 7 - When retrieving results I receive a keyvalue pair list or a list of empty objects

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm converting some old code from Nest 1.9.4 to the brand new version Nest 7.4.

In the old code we queried from an alias index that returned multiple types of objects so we used object as a generic type, like this:

`var response = ElasticClient.Search<object>(search)`

After the search was done we took Documents collection from response and separated our objects based on their type: 
`var posts = response.Documents.OfType<Blog.Post>;`

Here lies the first problem, with the current Nest implementation, if I provide "object" as the generic type I receive a IReadOnlyCollection with each attribute of my document as a Dictionary. It forces me to change my code but no big deal, I'm aware that the version the current implementation uses is way outdated but it is not that easy to convert this kind of result to an actual object.

The second problem is that if I change my code to query the correct type `var response = ElasticClient.Search<Blog.Post>(search)` elasticsearch returns the correct number of hits but the documents attributes are null, all of them.

If I try deserializing the response from the server using my types it works fine.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: Could you share `search` object?

Comment: Are you using version 7 of elasticsearch? Nest versions should match elasticsearch versions.

Comment: Yes, Nest 7 with Elastic 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very big difference that you are going to run into is that in NEST 1.9.4, Elasticsearch contains a `_type` in the hit metadata for each hit that is a match for the query. In conjunction with the `_index` in the metadata, NEST can deserialize the `_source` JSON object of each hit into the expected POCO. In your example, although you specified `object` as the type of each document to return, NEST can deserialize some of these documents to `Blog.Post`, based on the index and type the client has been configured with. This then allows for filtering using LINQ's `.OfType<T>()` to work correctly.

[From Elasticsearch 6.0 onwards, types are being removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html), so there is no longer a `_type` field in the hit metadata that NEST can use to infer which POCO a document should be deserialized to. One way in which this can be resolved is by introducing a discriminator field to the document that can be used to determine what POCO type the document should ultimately be deserialized into. For example, you might consider [hooking up `JsonNetSerializer` from the Nest.JsonNestSerializer nuget package](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer), and [serializing type information to use when deserializing.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_serializing_type_information)

Comment: That makes sense, I was already handling the type to separate different objects in differente indices. I'm implementing the custom deserialization for now. Thanks